Squash 90% of the exchange questions?
One of the most asked questions in the bitcoin 'verse is the one of "Which exchanges? Where to buy?" According to the FAQ these questions are deemed as off-topic, however, it would provide value to the community if we could offer a generice answer to it.

I agree, and I have been flagging and voting thus, while trying to give an answer at the same time. I'd like to get the best of two worlds: Have something that is helpful to the asker and still be able to throw their question out.

Somebody was thinking along the same line a long time ago already: What is a good resource explaining the best ways to buy bitcoin noob friendly

I have offered a bounty on http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-do-you-obtain-bitcoins"

We already have a question that tries to address this topic in a generic way: How do you obtain bitcoin?
I have created a bounty to update answers to this question to cover:
What are the ways to acquire bitcoins? Is there a website that gives an extensive overview of the operating exchanges (As in customer satisfaction, offered features, traded currencies, fee schedule, location and so forth.)?
Should this effort produce an excellent answer we could consolidate the existing duplicate questions and relay any future questions to it.
